# Is C++ variadic template pack expansion into multiple template types (such as std::shared_ptr) possible?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, variadic

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack

I have a function with a signature like this

```
    template <typename FirstType, typename ...NextTypes>
    static std::vector<std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<FirstType>, std::shared_ptr<NextTypes...>>>
```

When my true intention is to declare something that means this

```
    template <typename FirstType, typename ...NextTypes>
    static std::vector<std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<FirstType>, std::shared_ptr<NthType>, std::shared_ptr<NthType>>>
```

I would prefer not to pass the template types in as shared_ptr.
Is it possible/how?

Comment: Specifically, when I try to call this template function with three types I get " substitution failure... too many template arguments for class template 'shared_ptr' "

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<NextTypes...>` -> `std::shared_ptr<NextTypes>...`

Comment: Thank you Miles, so simple in hindsight :)

Comment: Pack expansion (and fold expressions as a consequence) can be a bit confusing. The way I remember what will be repeated (expanded) is which bit is closest to the `...`. In your case it was `NthType...` so it will try to do something like `shared_ptr<int, double, float, int, string>` which is invalid. If you are already familiar with regular expressions, another way to remember is it is akin to (\d)+.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to expand template parameter pack into multiple tuple elements. Here's how to do it, for example:

```
template <typename FirstType, typename ...NextTypes>
static std::vector<std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<FirstType>, std::shared_ptr<NextTypes>...>> some_function(FirstType t, NextTypes... n) {
    return { make_tuple(make_shared<FirstType>(t), make_shared<NextTypes>(n)...) };
}
```

After calling the function, you get a vector with tuple that stores three `std::shared_ptr` pointers:

```
int main() {
    int* ip = nullptr;
    long* lp = nullptr;
    double* dp = nullptr;

    auto v = some_function(ip, lp, dp);
    auto t = v.front();

    auto sp = get<1>(t);
    if (sp) cout << "Not NULL" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I am doing, but still solved it! Haha. Curiously (and maybe haphazardly) I'm using some other template functions/recursion/RTTI from here to create a vector of tuples from a shared base class.